# How to upload ebooks to Google Play Books using a script?

Tags: google-play-books

Both the Google Play books website and the Google Play books Android application, have the ability to upload your own ebooks. I wish to perform the same thing using a script written in python3 or nodejs.

I have taken a look at the API and, it seems that it is only for retrieving information about the various books.

I am wondering whether I'll have to achieve this using something like Google Chrome CDP to use the Goolge Play Books website itself to upload books or can this be done using the API and it's undocumented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this.Automated uploading to Google play books by using the website itself via selenium and it's chrome driver.